# How do I bend a cylinder like this?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging

I'm adding a necklace to a character I have. I made a hollow cylinder and need to bend it to fit the model[image]

Comment: Have you tried proportional editing?

Answer (score 4):

One way could be use a cloth simulation, very rough example:

[image]

which  works like:

[image]

here after adding a subsurf (as last modifier)

[image]

Comment: Try placing the solidify after the cloth for a cleaner result. The necklace should probably have a constant thickness anyways.

Comment: @Brenticus I get better results with solidify before... if it's after, collision is much worse... anyway it was just an example. Now I've put a better gif. I hope, at least.

Comment: That makes sense. The other option then is to apply the modifiers, remove the thickness manually, then re add it after to stop any intersections.

Comment: will this stay that way when exported?

Comment: @AlectPrasad find a frame you like more, apply modifiers (in order)...now it's just a deformed mesh. Use it as you wish.